# Using popover with JStree

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jstree, popover

I was wondering if there was a way to use popover with jstree. I have a jstree and I want to bring up a popover whenever a node is clicked.

What I have so far is:

```
// Left click jstree node for popover 
$("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data){

    //Code to display tooltip/popover
});
```

I am not sure how to get the popover to display and I'm not sure how the popover knows what html element to display on.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

```
}).bind('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
   if(!$("li[id='"+data.node.id+"'] > a").hasClass("popovers"))
   {
      $("li[id='"+data.node.id+"'] > a").addClass("popovers");
   }
      $("li[id='"+data.node.id+"'] > a").popover(
            { trigger: "hover",container: '#TreeCode',title:'Test'
                              ,content:"Test",placement:'left',offset: '0 10px' });
})
```

The initialization of the popover will help you in creating it. Also, you can use the `data object dynamically to show different data on popover events.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
//bootstrap tooltipped nodes list
var tooltipped_nodes = [];
$('#jstree')
// listen for event
.on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    $('#jstree ul li a').each(function(index, item){
        if (jQuery.inArray(index, tooltipped_nodes) == -1){
            $(this).tooltip({
                'placement': 'right',
                'trigger': 'click',
                'title': "Hover over me"
            });
            tooltipped_nodes.push(index);
        }
    });
});
```

On `open_node.jstree` event you can call Bootstrap `.tooltip()` function on the node(s) you want; in this example I loop each `<a>` tag in the `#jstree` list and add the same tooltip.
In order to avoid further calls on same nodes I push each "tooltipped" node index in `tooltipped_nodes` array, but maybe there can be a more efficient way out there to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () { 
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
```

...your parameter definitions

```
  .on('ready.jstree hover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    $("#ui-id-3").attr({"title":"Title #1","data-bs-toggle":"tooltip","data-bs-html":"true", "data-bs-offset":"0,6", "data-bs-placement":"right"});
    $("#node_2_anchor").attr({"title":"Title #2","data-bs-toggle":"tooltip","data-bs-html":"true", "data-bs-offset":"0,6", "data-bs-placement":"right"});
    $("#node_3_anchor").attr({"title":"Title #3","data-bs-toggle":"tooltip","data-bs-html":"true", "data-bs-offset":"0,6", "data-bs-placement":"right"});
    $("#node_4_anchor").attr({"title":"Title #4","data-bs-toggle":"tooltip","data-bs-html":"true", "data-bs-offset":"0,6", "data-bs-placement":"right"});
    $("#node_0_anchor").attr({"title":"Root<br/>Folder","data-bs-toggle":"tooltip","data-bs-html":"true", "data-bs-offset":"0,6", "data-bs-placement":"right"});
    //create bootstrap tooltips
    let tooltipTriggerList2 = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    let tooltipList2 = tooltipTriggerList2.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
    }); 
    
    }).on('dehover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
$('.tooltip').remove();
});
});
```

After this you might want to add the following functions to deal with the generated tooltips..

```
$(document).on('show.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).data('trigger') == 'mouseenter mouseover click') {
    let timeoutDataName = 'shownBsTooltipTimeout';
    if ($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName) != null) {
      clearTimeout($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName));
    }
    let timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $(e.target).click(); 
      $('.tooltip').remove();
    }, 1000);
    $(e.target).data(timeoutDataName, timeout);
  }
});
```

//hide tooltips

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).data('trigger') == 'mouseleave mouseout click') {
    let timeoutDataName = 'shownBsTooltipTimeout';
    $('.tooltip').remove();
    if ($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName) != null) {
      clearTimeout($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName));
    }
  }
});
```